# Passing value from service into directive

Tags: angularjs

Trying to figure out how to pass a value in service from one direction to another? I'm building a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS. It has 2 pages, home and results. On home, only functionality is autocomplete (using AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead), on results page, display results and search box. I'm trying to use a custom directive  to do this.

I basically have everything working EXCEPT, that when on the homepage, pressing the search button just goes to the results page, no search processing is done. AND everything works on the results page, autocomplete and search functions...

I recently put the ng-model(searchTerms) into its own service, but I DI that service into both my controllers. The only thing I can think of is that somehow my ng-model ISN'T getting passed to the directive? I'm stumped... still learning AngularJS directives.

Basically all the service does for searchTerms is

```
this.searchTerms = null;
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** I'm on v1.47 and using ngRoute for now.

**UPDATE 2** I have 2 way data binding working now. So when a query is submitted on the home page, the searchTerms variable now displays on the results page. However, there is still no results being displayed and no processing being performed. So just 2 way data binding is working.

**UPDATE 3**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('searchengine.query-service', [])
    .service('queryService', function() {
        var searchTerms;
        this.searchTerms = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider these 2 pages 'components', in the more update to date Angular jargon, and you want to navigate between them, passing your search term as a variable.

In your search page, you will need some code along the lines of

```
$router.navigate(['ResultsPage', {searchTerm: yourSearchTermGoesHere}]);
```

When the results component activates, it should check for the existence of a search term and perform whatever search processing is done when the search term subsequently changes.

Router docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router. Have a look specifically at the 'Extra Parameters' and 'Lifecycle hooks' section

Comment: I'm on 1.47 and using ngRoute for now, it seems that $routeParams would be the equivalent of what your talking about, right?

Comment: in my service should I change it to, var searchTerms;
  this.searchTerms = null;

Comment: Yes, I believe $routeParams is the equivalent. Can you post some of the code of your service please.

Comment: please look at UPDATE 3

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show me. Your controller needs to make a call to this service when the page loads.